# One or more of the Cache Types are invalidated: Blocks HTML output. How to fix this issue?

Tags: magento-1.9

When I tried to update my site, display following error.

***One or more of the Cache Types are invalidated: Blocks HTML output. Click here to go to Cache Management and refresh cache types.***

How to fix this issue permanently?

[image: Error Message]

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing to fix, this is not an error, magento is letting you know that you need to flush cache to see the latest changes.

Read this:
https://blog.amasty.com/magento-cache-explained-a-guide-for-store-owners/

Comment: block_html invalidates every time the magento cronjob runs. So this rather is a problem that needs fixing.